# Django, mod_wsgi--daemon mode, 403 Forbidden, works when in /var/www/html

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, http-status-code-403

When I move **/home/django/mysite** to **/var/www/html/mysite**, *and* **chown -R apache:apache**, *it works*.  But leaving in the home directory I get 403 forbidden.

I've literally spent a good 6 hours trying to get this to work.  HUGE progress for me to see that it works in /var/www/html, as I know all my "config" settings are correct.

Here is my httpd.conf

(first setting had to add to stop 503 internal server error)

```
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi

<VirtualHost 208.115.206.227:80>
 WSGIDaemonProcess django user=django group=django python-path=/home/django/mysite
 WSGIProcessGroup django

     ServerAdmin webmaster@mktrn.net
     ServerName endor.mktrn.net
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/django/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory /home/django/mysite/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So again, the above works if I just replace /home/django/mysite, with /var/www/html.

**I'm running mod_wsgi as daemon under the user django**--so I don't think that is it. What am I doing wrong?  I know it's not smart to put in /var/www/html, even if I have no document root, so really want to figure this out!

Answer (score 1):

A home directory such as /home/django would normally not be readable to others and so the user that Apache runs as would not be able to see into that directory and so access would be forbidden. This is why it would work when you move it elsewhere.

Comment: but I'm running mod_wsgi as the user 'django' (daemon mode) so wouldn't that give it access?  If not, what do I need to do?

Comment: The Apache user must have read/search access for directories all the way from the root directory down to the directory the WSGI script file is in. The WSGI script file itself need not be readable by Apache if using daemon mode and running it as different user, but those directories must be able to be read so Apache can at least detect that the file exists.